# Sertonin JSON: how to read a JSON array into a Java List?

Tags: java, javascript, android, json, arrays

Here is my code:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(readTwitterFeed);
List<Result> results = reader.read(new TypeDefinition(List.class, Result.class));
```

Result is a simple class with just one String member. readTwitterFeed is the JSON passed back from this call:
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/karimvarela.json

Do I need to cast the right side of the equation to (List)?

When I cast, I get a whole mess of errors that look like this:

```
`02-15 17:25:56.289: W/dalvikvm(18750): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
02-15 17:25:56.289: W/dalvikvm(18750): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 324: Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;.getName ()Ljava/lang/String;
02-15 17:25:56.289: W/dalvikvm(18750): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
02-15 17:25:56.289: W/dalvikvm(18750): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 324: Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;.getName ()Ljava/lang/String;
02-15 17:25:56.289: W/dalvikvm(18750): VFY: unable to resolve static method 456: Lorg/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils;.equals (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z
02-15 17:25:56.289: W/dalvikvm(18750): VFY: unable to resolve static method 323: Ljava/beans/Introspector;.getBeanInfo (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/beans/BeanInfo;
02-15 17:25:56.299: W/dalvikvm(18750): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 80 (Ljava/beans/IntrospectionException;)
02-15 17:25:56.299: W/dalvikvm(18750): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0xa4
02-15 17:25:56.299: W/dalvikvm(18750): VFY:  rejected Lcom/serotonin/json/JsonContext;.getConverter (Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/serotonin/json/spi/ClassConverter;
02-15 17:25:56.299: W/dalvikvm(18750): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x00a4
02-15 17:25:56.299: W/dalvikvm(18750): VFY:  rejected Lcom/serotonin/json/JsonContext;.getConverter (Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/serotonin/json/spi/ClassConverter;
02-15 17:25:56.299: W/dalvikvm(18750): Verifier rejected class Lcom/serotonin/json/JsonContext;
02-15 17:25:56.299: W/dalvikvm(18750): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750): java.lang.VerifyError: com.serotonin.json.JsonContext
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at com.serotonin.json.JsonReader.<init>(JsonReader.java:48)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at com.wmg.serotoninjsontest.SerotoninJSONTest.onCreate(SerotoninJSONTest.java:39)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
02-15 17:25:56.319: E/AndroidRuntime(18750):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You compiled your class with version of jar which has class "com.serotonin.json.JsonContext" and you are running with a different version of that jar.
Check your classpath.